# Antonym for "formal methods"

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, antonyms, software

In writing about verification techniques, I want to discuss [formal methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods) vs. other methods (e.g., testing or code review). While `informal` is the generally the antonym of `formal`, referring to these other methods as `informal methods` makes me feel like I'm describing them as slap-dash, low-quality approaches, which is not my intent.

For context, I'm looking for a good title for a goal node in [GSN](http://www.goalstructuringnotation.info/) that these non-formal verification methods (to partially use a suggestion from @EdwinAshworth) would be sub-goals under. Again, just to make sure this is crystal clear, these verification methods are *not* meant to be represented as inferior to formal methods, merely different from formal methods.

Does anyone have a good antonym for `formal methods` that is devoid of any negative connotations?

Comment: You need to add a supported definition of 'formal method' here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — I added a link to Wikipedia. I expect that those who aren't at least passingly familiar with the term, however, will be less likely to be able to come up with a suitable antonym.

Comment: The term non-formal exists (though it may already have a conflicting specific usage). However, this is hardly everyday English, so I'm voting that it is off-topic on ELU. I suggest you try Computer Science SE.

Comment: @BenHocking 1) You are unlikely to find anyone here with at least a possing familiarity with the subject. You'd probably have better luck on an SE site with people who do, like the couple of CS sites in particular. 2) any term for a specialized area of science is not likely (it might but it's not likely) to have a specific term for those outside of it. What is the antonym of 'artificial intelligence'? What is the antonym of 'computer architecture'? You might have words for _counterparts_ but again it depends.

Comment: You may want to be as literal as possible and use a couple more words and say 'those outside the formal methods community'. Knowing the tiniest bit about formal methods, though, I would think that test suites and code review, though not as central as things like static code analysis or assertion proofs, are still necessary.

Comment: @Mitch — I'm not sure what your last comment means. Literal about what? Who are you referring to outside the formal methods community? The fact that test suites and code review are still necessary is exactly the point I'm trying to make and why I want to avoid "informal".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — non-formal definitely sounds better to me than informal. I'm hoping for an even better answer. And maybe I'm wrong that knowing what formal methods are is that important to answering the question. To use Mitch's example, I would consider "biological intelligence" to be a decent antonym of "artificial intelligence", in most contexts.

Comment: @BenHocking see? it all depends on context. What is _not_ AI? To me it is the rest of computer science. I'm guessing that you want to refer to things within the software _engineering_ area that are not within the scope of formal methods. If you're looking for writing advice, I'd suggest that you introduce 'formal methods' by example, mention some things that are not considered part of formal methods, and eventually 'non-formal methods' would work. I don't think you can start off whatever your writing with 'Non-formal methods are blah blah blha..."

Comment: @Mitch — actually, this is part of a structured argument (http://www.goalstructuringnotation.info/), so what I'm looking for is a concise way to describe these approaches that fits into an argument node. The methods themselves will be described in sub-nodes. The context here is that these are software verification approaches that are not formal methods.

Comment: @BenHocking Probably best then to look at how other papers word things. What kind of software verification methods are there that are not considered formal methods? (I can't think of any). But anyway, there probably are, but the people who would know what they are would probably be the better people to ask (or to look at their writing to see how they refer to such things). It's easier to recognize things (reading a bunch of stuff and realizing when you see the words) than to recall (come up with the word or phrase out of the blue).

Comment: I don't think it is off-topic at https://cs.stackexchange.com to ask for terminology.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76689/discussion-between-ben-hocking-and-mitch).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Formal methods* use mathematical analysis to derive conclusions. **Empirical methods** use direct observation.

Here is an example of the phrases used in contrast:

- Estimating the relative usability of two interfaces: heuristic, formal, and empirical methods compared by Jakob Nielsen, Victoria L Phillips [- ACM Digital Library](https://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?q=empirical+methods+formal+methods&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC-cTO3tvaAhVLkpQKHfv0DtkQgQMIIzAA#d=gs_qabs&p=&u=%23p%3Df0c1v4G1vG4J)

Comment: I like the idea of even further categorization as you've shown here. In addition to "heuristic" and/or "empirical" methods, I'm also now considering "observational" methods (e.g., code review), but I'm still on the fence on that. Thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: I should add that, as I'm expanding my argument, I'm realizing that in a narrow context "natural language" is my antonym — e.g., formal requirements vs. natural language requirements, and same with specifications.

Comment: (Your antonym still works at the level I'm wanting it, though.)

Comment: @Ben Glad to have provided the inspiration. :)

Comment: @Ben ‘Code review’ provides an environment for deriving conclusions, but it doesn’t seem to be an alternative reasoning process for that derivation. For example, the content of the review might be to check the logic of a formal methods analysis.

Comment: With natural language, this sounds like either (1) the domain of interest, for which you can use either method of reasoning, or (2) the language of specification, with which you can express both styles. It doesn’t sound like another style of reasoning *per se*.

Answer (score 2):

What about an **heuristic technique**? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic):

> A **heuristic technique**, often called simply a heuristic, is any approach to problem solving, learning, or discovery that employs a practical method not guaranteed to be optimal or perfect, but sufficient for the immediate goals. Where finding an optimal solution is impossible or impractical, heuristic methods can be used to speed up the process of finding a satisfactory solution.

The difference between an algorithm (which might be considered a formal method) and an heuristic from a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2334257/3367799), credit goes to [*M. Borgwardt*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16883/michael-borgwardt):

> An algorithm is typically deterministic and proven to yield an optimal result
>
> A heuristic has no proof of correctness, often involves random elements, and may not yield optimal results.

Attribution:

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic)"Heuristic." Wikipedia. April 26, 2018. Accessed April 28, 2018. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic.

[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2334257/3367799) M. Borgwardt "What Is the Difference between a Heuristic and an Algorithm?" Definition - What Is the Difference between a Heuristic and an Algorithm? - Stack Overflow. Accessed April 28, 2018. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2334257/3367799.

Comment: I like both of yours and @Lawrence's answers, but I think his is a slightly better fit. Thanks!